# Repeat a Number of Elements Given a Number in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following object binded to the `$scope` of my Angularjs application

```
{name: 'Vampire Cafe', rating: 4, review: "Food was good, cafe was a bit dark..."}
```

I'd like to take the value of the `rating` and repeat a number of icon elements on my DOM totaling that value

So given the object above, the element would repeat 4 times, and the DOM would look like so:

```
<h3>Rating</h3>
<i class="icon-ios-star"></i>
<i class="icon-ios-star"></i>
<i class="icon-ios-star"></i>
<i class="icon-ios-star"></i>
```

How can I do this with a simple Angularjs expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, `ng-repeat` only accepts a collection as a parameter, but you could do this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

And somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.number = 5;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

This would allow you to change `$scope.number` to any number as you please and still maintain the binding you're looking for.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/cHQLH/) with a couple of lists using the same `getNumber` function.

Comment: Very clean solution!